# mongo DB aggregtion with $cond returning value from field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to have an `aggregation` that returns a field (in a document) if two conditions are met, 
I am doing it at `$project` stage and tried to write it as follows :

```
"conversionName" : { "$cond" : [ { "$and" : [ { "$eq" : [ "$webpage", "Product" ] }, { "$eq" : [ "$isConverted", true ] } ] }, "$conversion.name", 0 ] }
```

so if webpage is Product and isConverted is true then it shows the value of the conversion.name at this document.

```
The current aggregation fails due to :  "The $cond accumulator is a unary operator' on server main-shard-00-00-mhxad.gcp.mongodb.net:27017. "
```

The other parts of the aggregations work perfectly fine.

In what way can I return a value with a `$cond` commend? If there is non - what another way may address my needs?

Answer (score 0):

In my project, it works perfectly this way :

```
$cond: {
  if: {
    $and: [
      { "$eq" : [ "$webpage", "Product" ] },
      { "$eq" : [ "$isConverted", true ] },
    ],
  },
  then: "$conversion.name",
  else: 0,
},
```

If it does not work (and I dont' see why it won't) `then` is an expression and can be an other `$cond` :

```
$cond: {
  if: { "$eq" : [ "$webpage", "Product" ] },
  then: {$cond: {if: { "$eq" : [ "$isConverted", true ] }, then: "$conversion.name", else: 0},
  else: 0,
},
```